# Pattern matching while reading from the files using Perl

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I'm running into issue while reading a file and matching the pattern

**File content**

```
1: Recturing Svc
2: Finance
    :
    :
9: Payments
    :
    :
19: Mobile
     :
     :
29: Bankers
```

My Code looks like this

```
open(INPUTFILE, "<$conf_file") or die("unable to open text file");
foreach (<INPUTFILE>) {
  print "$_";
}
close INPUTFILE;

print "Please choose a number from the list above: ";
chop($input = <STDIN>);
$input = trim($input);
print "Your Choice was: $input\n";

$TEMP = "$input:";
open(INPUTFILE, "<$conf_file") or die("unable to open text file for comparision");
foreach $line (<INPUTFILE>) {
  if ($line =~ /$TEMP/) {
    print " exact match: $& \n";
    print " after match: $' \n";
    $svc = $';
    print "ServiceL $svc \n";
  }
}
close INPUTFILE;
```

It is matching multiple items, for example `9:` and `19:` and `29:` when I select. For example, if I enter 9 then it prints

```
 9: Payments
19: Mobile
29: Bankers
```

Comment: try `if($line =~ /^$TEMP:/) {` to match only at the beginning of the line and with a following `:`

Comment: I can add somethingg like /^$TEMP/ but this will break at 90.

Comment: yes, because you have to include the `:` - since you know for sure, that the number is followed by a  colon. so you want to search for `/^9:/` and not `/^9/`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read your options file into an array so that it doesn't need to be opened and read twice

Something like this perhaps? The regular expression in `if $input =~ /(\d+)/` extracts any number from the input so there is no need to remove spaces or the newline, while `and $menu[$1]` checks that such a number exists in the menu

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $conf_file = 'conf_file.txt';

my @menu;
{
  open my $fh, '<', $conf_file or die qq{Unable to open "$conf_file" for input: $!};
  while ( <$fh> ) {
    if ( /(\d+)\s*:\s*(.*\S)/ ) {
      $menu[$1] = $2;
      print;
    }
  }
}

my $option;
until ( $option) {
  print "Please choose a number from the list above: ";
  my $input = <STDIN>;
  $option = $1 if $input =~ /(\d+)/ and $menu[$1];
}

print "Your Choice was: $option\n";
print "Corresponding to $menu[$option]\n";
```

**output**

```
E:\Perl\source>conf_file.pl
1: Recturing Svc
2: Finance
9: Payments
19: Mobile
29: Bankers
Please choose a number from the list above: 3
Please choose a number from the list above: 9
Your Choice was: 9
Corresponding to Payments
```